# From Ubuntu 18 to 20: Plex Media Server updates

Tags: server

I recently updated my NUC to 20.04. Since then I'm not able tu update my existing Plex Media Server using graphical UI. So, now, I have to use Terminal, but it's not so easy for me. Is there any way to use again the GUI? I heard of Snap packages... but what am I supposed to do, when I already have PMS installed in order to properly use a Snap Package like this? https://snapcraft.io/plexmediaserver

Thanks.

edit in order to clarify, I hope

Thanks, I installed Plex using Terminal, long time ago, on Ubuntu 18 and I was always able, from my browser, to update, when prompted. Now, with Ubuntu 20.04, I download the file, but Ubuntu Software is not able to update it. And I have to use Terminal command.

edit#2 snap list plexmediaserver give this "error: no matching snaps installed"
and
dpkg -l | grep plexmediaserver give this "ii  plexmediaserver                            1.20.3.3437-f1f08d65b                 amd64        Plex organizes all of your personal media so you can easily access and enjoy it."

Comment: Yes, I know that I'm running the latest version... That's why I was able to use Terminal. But.. I'd prefer to use a GUI...

Comment: What changed that leads you to believe that you cannot continue to use the same web-interface tool to upgrade the package? (Remember that we are not there; we cannot see what you are experiencing)

Comment: With Ubuntu 18 Ubuntu software was able to install any PMS update. Now, with Ubuntu 20, Ubuntu Software keeps giving me an error and is not able to perform the update by itself (that's why I have to run commands in Terminal). English is not my first language, so please be patient :-)

Comment: What is the Ubuntu Software error? (Please show us the *exact* error, as complete as possible)

Comment: unfortunately to get the error, I should try to install the update; at the moment I'm running the latest version, so... probably I'll keep you posted, after the next release.

Comment: If the error occurred recently, a record would be in your /var/log/apt/history.log and /var/log/apt/term.log. term.log would have the exact error wording.

Comment: For now I'm giving up... I'll write again, at the next Plex update. Thanks for your help!